# No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement when multiple queries

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM news");
$news = $result->fetch_assoc();


$data = "test";
$query = "UPDATE news SET last_query = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), news = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
var_dump($mysqli->error); # empty
var_dump($stmt->bind_param("s", $data)); # true
var_dump($stmt->prepare($query)); # true
var_dump($stmt->execute()); # false
var_dump($stmt->error); # No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement
$stmt->close();
```

Removing the first query, causes the second to function normally from what I read this is from results remaining in the result set (even though it's reading form a single row database). But even clearing the result set with $result->free(); doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Is that a valid second query? Does your `news` table also have a column called `news`?

Comment: You `prepare` the query twice (once invalidly) but only `execute` it once. Remove the second `prepare` and you should be fine.

Comment: I'm confused as to the question. Also, the line `$data "test"` should read `$data = "test"`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo the problem was what Jon said. $stmt->prepare is for retrieving data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$stmt->prepare` is for reading data and shouldn't be used when updating a table.